# find out url from given paragraph using regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

can anyone help me find out url  from given paragraph  using regex c#

Note: Paragraph may contain string and url also

```
Input like this 
"My website   http://www.google.com/myMail/1212  this is my favorite website"


out put looks:
My website <a href='http://www.google.com/myMail/1212'>http://www.google.com/myMail/1212</a> this is my favorite website
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stolen from [here](http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-Extract-URLs.html):

```
public string[] ExtractURLs(string str)
{
    // match.Groups["name"].Value - URL Name
    // match.Groups["url"].Value - URI
    string RegexPattern = @"<a.*?href=[""'](?<url>.*?)[""'].*?>(?<name>.*?)</a>"

    // Find matches.
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches
        = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(str, RegexPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    string[] MatchList = new string[matches.Count];

    // Report on each match.
    int c = 0;
    foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches)
    {
        MatchList[c] = match.Groups["url"].Value;
        c++;
    }

    return MatchList;
}
```

Googling can really pay off you know

Answer (score 0):

Taken straight from [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]", "<a href=\"$0\">$0</a>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Note that the protocol is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mr. M.edmondson

Googling helped me  , got the answer below

```
string FindUrl(string url)
{
    Regex r1= new Regex("((http://|www\\.)([A-Z0-9.-:]{1,})\\.[0-9A-Z?;~&#=\\-_\\./]{2,})",    RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    MatchCollection mc = r1.Matches(url);
    foreach (Match m in mc)
    {
        url = url.Replace(m.Value, "<a href='" + m.Value + "'>" + m.Value + "</a>");
    }
    return url;
}
```